# Can we Implement adobe muse with magento?

Tags: magento, muse

> how to implement adobe muse with CMS like magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking a web designer question on a programming section. Since their major blurb is:

> Create gorgeous, custom websites without writing code.
>
> If you know Adobe InDesign you’ll know Adobe Muse, the graphic designer’s favorite web-building app. Skip the coding and quickly design unique sites using familiar features and shortcuts, and integrate third-party functionality like blogs and shopping carts.

it probably doesn't fit well with database driven, template presentation websites. A product built for people who don't want to get their hands dirty, or if they're attempting to run Magento, need to hire people who understand the programming issues needed to run it.